# Using MvcUriComponentsBuilder::fromMethodCall with String as the return type

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'd like to use the `MvcUriComponentsBuilder::fromMethodCall` method to build URLs from my controllers. I normally have a String return type (which returns the view name) and a Model instance as method parameter in my controller methods like:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String foo(Model uiModel) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("pi", 3.1415);
        return "fooView";
    }
}
```

I try to generate a URL e.g. like:

```
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodCall(on(MyController.class).foo(null)).build().toUriString();
```

This leads to this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class java.lang.String
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
```

This happens because the String return type wants to get proxied, but can't as a final class.

What's a way to overcome this? I'd like to keep the String as a return type and get the Model as input from a parameter in my controller methods because IMHO it's way easier than handling a ModelAndView instance in every controller method.

Answer (score 4):

fromMethodCall uses CGLIB proxy in the process which is why you run into the issue. This article details why.**https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/155**. Try using fromMethodName if you want to maintain the String return types.

```
MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(MyController.class, "foo", new Object()).build();
```

Comment: Did it help. I am curious to find out if there was an alternative.

Comment: Having the method names as strings scattered all over the place makes everything very fragile to refactoring so I'd rather not do it like this. I was just wondering if there's an easy way to get the string representation of a java 8 method reference so that you could use something like: `MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(MyController.class, methodName(MyController::foo), new Object()).build();`. Even better if the MvcUriComponentsBuilder would support method references in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the signature of the method to return Spring's `ModelAndView` vs. returning `String`. For example:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public ModelAndView foo() {
        return new ModelAndView("fooView", "pi", 3.1415);
    }
}
```

With this refactored signature, the corresponding `fromMethodCall` invocation would look like this:

```
UriComponents uri = fromMethodCall(on(MyController.class).foo()).build();
```